# SQL Server trigger with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, constraints

I'd like to create an `INSERT` trigger for SQL Server 2008 with a condition.

For example I've a transactions table with 2 types of transactions A and B.
I'd like the trigger to fire when there's an insert transaction of only A type.

How do I do that?

I'll be very happy to get and example if possible

Thanks

**TABLE**:

```
Txn     Txn Date
---------------------------
A       2018-08-01 01:05:00
A       2018-08-01 01:05:01
B       2018-08-01 01:05:05
B       2018-08-01 01:05:09
A       2018-08-01 01:05:15
B       2018-08-01 01:05:41
```

Comment: `INSERT`s aren't limited to just inserting a *single* row at a time. Somebody could easily write an `INSERT` that inserts a combination of rows, *some* of which are `A` and some of which are not. In SQL Server, triggers fire one per statement, not once per row. You need to write a trigger that properly deals with these multiple rows and deals with the `A` rows in a *set-based* fashion. Since we don't know *what you want to do with them* though, it's difficult to offer *concrete* advice here.

Comment: In my case, there's a single statement with single row. I need a basic trigger structure how to write this condition. All the forums that I've checked I didn't find even one example to learn from

Comment: Maybe so, but I would always describe any trigger that only works for single row inserts as **broken**. I will give a grudging pass mark to triggers that explicitly check for multiple rows and bail out with an error. But any trigger that silently does the wrong thing in the face of multiple rows can only be described as broken.

Comment: Can you give an example how to write it with unbroken method?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated.  You need an `instead of` trigger.

```
create trigger trig_transactions_type on transactions
instead of insert as
begin
    if (not exists (select 1
                    from inserted i
                    where type = 'B'
                   )
        )
    begin
       raiseerror ('Type "B" is required', 10, 1)
       rollback transaction;
    end;
    else
    begin
       insert into transactions (type, txn_date, . . .)
           select type, txn_date, . . .
           from inserted;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have idea of mysql : you can check that on insert condition on single column how to execute trigger to insert on single row in a new table for an example:

DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$
CREATE   TRIGGER `TestTrigger` AFTER INSERT ON `testtable` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.TXN = 'A'  THEN
            INSERT INTO `testb`(columna,columnb) VALUES(1,'Suresh');
    END IF;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

#

Test Table structures is as:

CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `txn` BIGINT(12) DEFAULT '0',
  `txn_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ind_msisdn` (`txn`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `testb` (
  `columna` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnb` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT ''
) ;

Comment: `DELIMITER` and `FOR EACH ROW` tell us that, whatever this variant of SQL is, it's *not* T-SQL, which, since the question is tagged [tag:sql-server-2008], is what the OP would be looking for.